# Quadratic regression with orthogonal polynomials vs. raw polynomials with QR decomposition

Tags: polynomial, orthogonal, rstan, qr-decomposition

I'm using rstanarm to estimate random slopes for second-order polynomial coefficients. My model has the basic form:

`mod <- stan_lmer(y ~ x + I(x^2) + (x + I(x^2) | user_id))`

I received warning messages about divergent transitions, increased adapt_delta, and tested the following models:

```
# many divergent transitions
mod_a <- stan_lmer(y ~ x + I(x^2) + (x + I(x^2) | user_id), QR = TRUE) 

# moderate divergent transitions
mod_b <- stan_lmer(y ~ poly(x, 2, raw = FALSE) + (poly(x, 2, raw = FALSE) | user_id)) 

# no divergent transitions
mod_c <- stan_lmer(y ~ poly(x, 2, raw = FALSE) + (poly(x, 2, raw = FALSE) | user_id), QR = TRUE)
```

My understanding is that `poly()` generates orthogonal polynomials using QR decomposition, so I was expecting mods a-c models to perform similarly (acknowledging that coefficient estimates would vary between raw & orthogonal space). However, `mod_a` failed to converge, `mod_b` converged with many iterations & high adapt_delta, and `mod_c` converged without issue. All models used default weakly informative priors.

My questions: (1) how do these approaches differ? and (2) Is it problematic to specify `QR = TRUE` with `poly(x, 2, raw = FALSE)` ?